# How to install APT on Debian Linux

Tags: linux, installation, debian, apt

I've uninstalled APT due to A LOT of issues, but it seems that I can't install it again. Can someone please help me? I'm running Linux kali 3.12-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.12.6-2kali1 (2014-01-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to follow the instructions outlined in this link:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25770/how-to-reinstall-apt-on-debian

It may take some digging and manually exploring the Kali and Debian repositories, but you might be able to find the package you are looking to install and pull it down via the dpkg command.

Comment: Thanks! I used this link though (Just going to post it to help others out): http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.9.7.9+deb7u1_amd64.deb